# Is it possible to write data to a BLE broadcasting device?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

My current understanding of the BLE gap role "broadcast" is that it broadcasts data packets with no option to connect to that device.
My question is therefore: is it possible to combine the gap broadcaster with a gatt server that contains a writable characteristic, so that gatt clients still have the option to write to the gatt server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can combine the Broadcaster role with the Peripheral role, to achieve what you want.